# Android live wallpaper not displayed in the list

Tags: java, android, live-wallpaper

I'm a noob in android development. And i was trying out the livewallpaper development. I got the code done without any errors.. but then the livewallpaper is not diplayed in the list of live wall papers in my avd

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ani.trial.lwp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <service 
           android:name="ani.trial.lwp.mainservice"
           android:label="Trial"
           android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
           <intent-filter >
               <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService"/>
           </intent-filter>
               <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
                   android:resource="@xml/layout"/>
       </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and my main java code-

```
package ani.trial.lwp;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class mainservice extends WallpaperService {

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new RenderEngine();
    }

      @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
        }



                class RenderEngine extends Engine
            {
        boolean mVisible=true;

        RenderEngine(){

        }
        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible){
            mVisible = visible;
            if(visible)
            drawFrame();
        }

        private final Runnable mDrawScene = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                drawFrame();
            }
        };
        void drawFrame()
        {   
            //Don't render when not visible
            if(!mVisible) return;
            final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
            Canvas c= null;

            try
                {
                c=holder.lockCanvas();
                if(c!=null){
                    //TODO iterate through  sprites/renderables
                    //and render them here
                    c.drawColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if(c!=null) holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }

            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawScene);
            if(mVisible){
                mHandler.postDelayed(mDrawScene, 1000/30);
            }
        }
    }}
```

Any idea whats wrong people? I was trying out some tutorials and this is how i got it done. Also are there any good tutorials for live wallpaper development? I got some with renderscripts but i have no idea how to add them in eclipse.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two very good live wallpaper tutorials which you can follow :-

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/108390/How-To-Create-Android-Live-Wallpaper

For the icon to show in the Live wallpaper list, the xml file "layout", to which you are referring to,must have a code defined like this :

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <wallpaper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:settingsActivity="packagename.LiveWallpaperSettings"
android:thumbnail="@drawable/icon"/>
```

The thumbnail must be defined in it.

Comment: oh man.. the api used in vogella examples have been depreciated.. although the problem was that <wallpaper> tag should have had the W in lower case.. jeeze.. thanks anyway!